# Using draggable in an img object doesn't works fine in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I am trying to add drag'n drop funcionality to images galleries to the user to be able to move his images from one gallery to another.

I've started using the jQuery UI draggable() in  objects to test how it works. I've found that it works fine in Firefox but in Chrome when I try to drag an image it turns blue as if it where selected and to drop it I have to click again before release the mouse button or it still go following the mouse.

How can I solve it? Is any way to avoid Chrome images selection and dragging to use only the jQuery UI?

I know that I can put the images as  background but those are resized and resizing background images in IE doesn't work.

Comment: I've found the problem. It is a bug that has been solved in last jQuery UI versions. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Will add an answer in 7 hours, ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add an answer if there could be somone who needs it so I've found it looking at jQuery bugs tickets.

This issue is a bug that has been solved in last jQuery UI versions. Just update it.